# How can I keep adding on results obtained from each function call to the arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

John and his family went on a holiday and went to 3 different restaurants. The bills were $124, $48 and $268.

To tip the waiter a fair amount, John created a simple tip calculator (as a function). 
He likes to tip 20% of the bill when the bill is less than $50,
15% when the bill is between $50 and $200,
and 10% if the bill is more than $200.

In the end, John would like to have 2 arrays:
1) Containing all three tips (one for each bill)
2) Containing all three final paid amounts (bill + tip).

I have done the part where each function call with a different bill value returns the correct tip amount and total bill amount.

function billcalc(bill){

```
var tiplist=[];
    var finalAmount=[];
    var tip; var total;


if(bill<=50)
    {
        tip=0.2*bill;
        total=bill+tip;
        tiplist.push(tip);
        finalAmount.push(total);
        console.log(tiplist);
        console.log(finalAmount);

    }


else if(bill>=50 && bill<=200){
        tip=0.15*bill;
        total=bill+tip;
        tiplist.push(tip);
        finalAmount.push(total);
        console.log(tiplist);
        console.log(finalAmount);
    }


else{
        tip=0.10*bill;
        total=bill+tip;
        tiplist.push(tip);
        finalAmount.push(total);
        console.log(tiplist);
        console.log(finalAmount);
    }
}

billcalc(124);
billcalc(48);
billcalc(268);
```

I want to get the two arrays to display all the respective tip and total value from each function call.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for getting the factor for getting the tip and another function for calculating the tip.

As result add the values of bills and tips for getting all total values.

```js
function getFactor(v) {
    if (v < 50) return 0.2;
    if (v < 200) return 0.15;
    return 0.1;
}

function getTip(amount) {
    return +(amount * getFactor(amount)).toFixed(2); // apply some rounding
}

var bills = [124, 48, 268],
    tips = bills.map(getTip),
    totals = [bills, tips].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]));

console.log(tips);
console.log(totals);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is a very handy array method specifically for accumulating results when iterating over a collection.

Reduce takes a function as an argument, the function generally uses two arguments: the accumulator and the current element. The second argument given to reduce is the initial accumulator. I've defined the two result arrays which allows me to push to them for every iteration.

```
var result = [124, 48, 268].reduce(function(acc, bill) {
    var tip = 0;
    if(bill < 50){ tip = bill * 0.2 }
    if(50 <= bill && bill < 200){ tip = bill * 0.15 }
    if(200 < bill){ tip = bill * 0.1 }
    acc.tips.push(tip);
    acc.totals.push(bill + tip);
    return acc;
}, {tips: [], totals: []});
```

Which gives:

```
  {
  "tips": [
    18.599999999999998,
    9.600000000000001,
    26.8
  ],
  "totals": [
    142.6,
    57.6,
    294.8
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I merely had to put the two arrays outside the billCalc function and Voila!

Thanks for all the solutions given above.